# Connect guest OS (ubuntu) to genymotion on host machine

Tags: android, virtualbox, genymotion

I have an Ubuntu VM running on VirtualBox and an Android emulator running through Genymotion (which also uses VirtualBox), so I thought I could easily connect one VM to the other, right? Turns out it isn't so simple. I added a bridged adapter to the Ubuntu VM, restarted the ADB server and then ran `adb connect -emulatorIP-` This allows me to see the device, but the problem is that adb insists that the device is offline, when it quite clearly isn't. So I'd like to ask for help with this issue.

Comment: For what reason to you need the Ubuntu VM that you can't do on the host OS?

Comment: I'm developing on a Windows box, however my program is supposed to be able to work on Linux as well. I figured that it wasn't worth dualbooting just to run my program on another OS, especially since the computer doesn't belong to me!

Comment: here is another answer that worked for me the https://superuser.com/questions/1081919/use-adb-with-genymotion-from-concurrent-linux-vm/1248915#1248915

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So actually all you have to do is pretend that you're trying to connect to a remote device. On the host machine run

```
adb tcpip <port>
```

which will enable that port for remote connection. Then run in the VM

```
adb connect <deviceip>:<port>
```

to connect to the genymotion device.

For further reference: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html#wireless